# Network Flow Dataframe - Merging Memory Error - Unable to allocate array with shape and data type

Tags: pandas, data-science, network-flow

I have big 3 CSV files and they are all 76 same columns.
The number of rows are different
17809 rows - 124262 rows -  108779 rows
I am trying to merge these 3 data frames but I am having a memory error. Can I solve this issue or is it impossible for my hardware?
16GB Ram, i5 11th.

I found this solution to merge them but there is an error. I want them to be in one dataframe.

```
  from functools import reduce
    data_frames = [a, b, c]
    df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Intrusion'], how='outer'), data_frames)
    df_merged
```

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 101. GiB for an array with shape (13517346950,) and data type int64

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in Linux, I loved it.
awk 'FNR > 1' file1.csv file2.csv> output.csv
That is all.
https://predictivehacks.com/?all-tips=how-to-concatenate-multiple-csv-files-in-linux

Comment: What about the CSV headers? Won't this result in the headers appearing three times in the output file?

Comment: You are right, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Problem with current solution :- In this case we are also merging the header of all the files, which was actually not required in my case.  awk 'FNR > 1' file1.csv file2.csv> output.csv